# BoI erases my data

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, linux

I got Binding of Isaac for Linux through the Humble Bundle.   It works fine, and sometimes saves my data (things found, challenges unlocked, etc.), but then sometimes erases them - seemingly at random.   I've tried restoring what I thought was the save data (in ~/.macromedia/... I think), to no avail.   Any suggestions?   Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try installing it through Steam for Linux (assuming you are using a compatible distro)? While it's not officially listed, for some reason, Binding of Isaac utilises steam cloud and that may somehow salvage your saves.

Comment: I thought I read (in another question on this site, actually) that Steam doesn't handle saves for this game because it's Flash-based.   Anyway, I don't have Steam installed, and don't want to install it (especailly not just for this).   Thanks, though, good thought.

Comment: There is no steam version of binding of isaac for linux...